# Converting the output from dec_base64 function which will be binary to string in informatica

Tags: informatica

I am trying to convert the binary output from dec_base64 function in expression to string format in Java transformation. As I am new to java, can someone give the Java code which will be used in informatica to convert that decoded base64 binary data to string data.

Comment: you have to rephrase your question. what is your input and what kind of output you are expecting, what have you tried should really help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
finalString = new String(Base64.encode(binaryText));
```

In the other hand, if you want to convert string to bytes, you can try the next code:

```
byte[] binaryText = Base64.decode(finalString);
```

Comment: Thanks Mariyanova for the reply.